# PHP shortcodes are causing 403 errors

Tags: php, forms, http-status-code-403, php-ini

Here are the results of my observation of this weird behavior so far:

1. This error occurs only when the user posts a comment which contains `<?`. It does not occur when user types a comment with `< ?`, `?>` or `? >`. Now, `<?` is PHP shortcode so I thought that might be causing the problem. However, the error persisted even when I turned `short_open_tag` `Off` (It was `On` earlier) in PHP settings from cpanel.
2. To make sure that my code was not causing the problems, I did run some tests locally and on other hosting providers. The code worked in both cases without any errors even when the comments contained `<?`. I have been trying to figure out if there is an error in the code for past few weeks but I am positive that's not the case.

Is there any setting in `php.ini` which can cause 403 errors because of shortcodes?

This is the `urlencoded` form data for a successful comment:

```
comm_name=Test&comm_email=test%40test.com&comm_msg=%3F%3E+this+is+a+comment.&comm_token=13198eaf2c948cfa950e12d0173a1874&comm_submit=Post
```

The successful comment with no such error was:

```
?> this is a comment.
```

These are the request headers for a successful comment:

```
:method:POST
:path:/comments.php?
:scheme:https
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;
q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8
cache-control:max-age=0
content-length:137
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie:PHPSESSID=oe1ojg2kfdls7fabr983arkn36
```

These are the response headers for a successful comment:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,37,38,39"
cache-control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:2000
content-type:text/html
status:200
```

This is the `urlencoded` form data for a comment with 403 error:

```
comm_name=Test&comm_email=test%40test.com&comm_msg=%3C%3F+this+is+a+comment.&comm_token=f1189b4a6f4e4f3d279cb9fde66fde57&comm_submit=Post
```

The unsuccessful comment with 403 error was:

```
<? this is a comment.
```

The response headers stay the same for both successful and unsuccessful comments. The only difference is in the status code which changes from 200 to 403.

I get the comment text inside PHP using `$_POST['comm_msg']`. If there was an error in the script, I would have been able to replicate it on my local server as well as with other hosting servers so I don't think it is an issue with code.

My question is: Is there any setting in `php.ini` or `.htaccess` or any other file that can cause 403 errors because of PHP `shortcode` in `urlencoded` formats or in any other formats.